# using "wc -l" on script counts more than using on terminal

Tags: bash, shell, wc

I'm making a bash script and it's like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DNUM=$(ls -lAR / 2> /dev/null | grep '^d' | wc -l)
echo there are $DNUM directories.
```

the problem is, that when I run this line directly on the terminal:

```
ls -lAR / 2> /dev/null | grep '^d' | wc -l
```

I get a number.

But when I run the script it displays me a greater number, like 30 to 50 more.

What is the problem here?
Why is the "wc" command counting more lines when running it from a script?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the output without `wc -l` and seeing what the differences are? Are you running the script as your user or as some other user?

Comment: Are you trying to count directories?

Comment: Find a way to exclude /proc.

Comment: The difference in counts could easily be explained by the additional entries under `/proc` for additional running processes - a quick look at one `/proc/<pid>` entry on my current system shows 26 additional directories, but that will vary depending on kernel version and other things... You should use `find` with appropriate limiting clauses instead of `ls -R`.

Comment: the linux distribution is Slackware. And now I tried using `find / -type d | wc -l` and i got the same difference in the number. i get 48 more lines.

Comment: btw I'm running the script as root.

Comment: @JoseAndresMedinaO. Do you run the command you compare against as root? If not, that explains the difference (the script would include directories that your command's user doesn't have access to see)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `ls -R` is almost always the wrong answer for most questions about a filesystem.

Comment: And don't throw away errors `2> /dev/null` when you are trying to debug something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have different directory roots for the two runs. Instead of `ls` to find the directories only you can use this

```
find parent_directory -type d
```

and pipe to `wc -l` to count.

The `/proc` directory will have processes and treated as directories and will change from run to run.  To exclude it from the count use

```
find / -path /proc -prune -o -type d | wc -l
```

Comment: I tried using `find / -type d | wc -l` and i got the same difference in the number. i get 48 more lines. using that line on terminal i get like 30300, and using it inside the script i get 30348. the same as using ls...

Comment: what i am asking is why i get 48 more lines. I will use `find` instead of `ls`

Comment: Can you investigate what the differences are?  If the number is too large, you can do it in stages.  Add `-maxdepth n` and increment n from 1 until you get the different counts for both runs.

Comment: also every couple of minutes that i run the script i get a different count. Directories don't reproduce themself like cells!

Comment: I think the problem is /proc as reported above.  You have to exclude /proc.

Comment: @karakfa and any other pseudo-file-system like `/sys`, or `/dev` or `/var/run` or ...

Answer (score 0):

To find the differences in your exact case I would suggest to run

```
#!/bin/bash
for r in 1 2; do
  ls -lAR / 2> /dev/null | grep '^d' > run${r}.txt 1> out${r}.txt
done
diff -Nura out1.txt out2.txt
rm -f out1.txt out2.txt
```

But as the most ppl. already said it would make sense to exclude directories like `sys`,`proc` ...